# Gitlab CI not being able to distinguish hotfix branch after it's merged

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to create a separate pipeline when an MR is related to a hotfix. For this matter, I am making an assumption that whenever the branch name starts with hotfix/ then it needs to be treated differently. The below rule is what I have used for this matter:

```
rules:
    - if: '($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^hotfix\/.*$/) || ($CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "mater" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME =~ /^hotfix\/.*$/)'
```

This condition works when there is an MR created so the first part of the condition works as expected. However, the second part does not work as `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` does not exist. Apparently, when an MR is merged all traces of the source branch is removed so I am not sure how I can find out if that was a hotfix or not.

Comment: I think the first condition is enough to have a separate pipeline when an MR is related to a hotfix. Why do you need the second part of the condition (after `||`)

Comment: The second part of your conditional is evaluated for all Pipeline Sources, but the second variable (`$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`) only exists for Merge Request pipelines. But, if you add the conditional to ensure it's only a Merge Request pipeline, it's identical to the part before the `||`. Agree with @NicolasPepinster, it appears unnecessary.

Comment: @AdamMarshall that's correct. But there seems to be no way I can have a condition on the source branch after the MR is merged (the second part of the condition).